# Multiple foreign keys for a single ActiveRecord has_one Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that is related to an Office and Department.

```
class DataForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  belongs_to :department
end
```

I also have a third model that oversees many office/department combos.

```
class ManagementGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :office
   belongs_to :department
end
```

How would I say that the DataForm has an association to the ManagementGroup where the offices and departments are in sync with each other.

```
class DataForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office
  belongs_to :department
  # how would I get the below association to work 
  has_one :management_group, foreign_key: [:office_id, :department_id]
end
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the relationships, so if DataForm has exactly one ManagementGroup, why doesn't ManagementGroup belong to DataForm? Heck, I think DataForm should belong to ManagementGroup instead.

Comment: I guess it belongs to the Management Group purely based on its office/department combo.   I played with the idea of getting the actual PK of the Management Group and then storing that.  But that could lead to getting out of sync and additional updates instead of just using the data that already can make that association for me.

Answer (score 0):

**How would I say that the DataForm has an association to the ManagementGroup where the offices and departments are in sync with each other.** You can't do that. Instead, you restructure it so:

- A `DataForm` belongs to a `ManagementGroup`
- A `ManagementGroup` belongs_to an `:office` and a `:department`

Therefore, you can determine the `:office` and `:department` of your `DataForm` by looking at the `ManagementGroup` it `belongs_to`.

You could then access your `DataForm`'s ` office with something like:

```
@data_form.management_group.office
```

or better yet, use delegators. Example below:

```
class DataForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :management_group
  delegate :office, to: :management_group
  delegate :department, to: :management_group
end

class ManagementGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :office
   belongs_to :department
   has_many :data_forms
end
```

Then, you can just do:

```
@data_form.office
@data_form.department
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct way to go too, but I do not quite understand jared's business case.